# Django Haystack refuses to show no results, even for absurd queries

Tags: django, django-haystack

My question may be a bit strange, but it's been bothering me since the behavior is not what I expected. Here is my query:

```
query = request.GET.get('q','')
#in search_indexes:
#start_datetime = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='start_datetime',null=True)
#end_datetime = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='end_datetime')
search_events = SearchQuerySet().models(Event).filter(content=query).
                filter(end_datetime__gte=datetime.now()).
                order_by("start_datetime")
```

Now I type in a query like `"asdfasdfjasldf lolol hwtf asdlfka"` and I still get 3 results. (Note, I only have 5 events to start with. Not sure if that could affect anything.) I print out the scores, and they are `[42,42,42]`. Doesn't `filter()` match on exact phrases? Especially if I use quotes?

//edit
I also tried using `auto_query`, and the results are the same.

I'm really confused about what's happening, so hopefully somebody can help clear this up. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that someone else on my team had set HAYSTACK_DEFAULT_OPERATOR to 'OR' instead of 'AND'. Explains everything - the additional filter tag was actually expanding the number of results!

Comment: So you question is answered, right? Feel free to mark you own answer as correct answer.

Comment: yeah, the darn two-day wait period had me forgetting

Answer (score 1):

You might like to perform search using `auto_query()`:

```
search_events = SearchQuerySet().models(Event)
                                .auto_query(query)
                                .filter(end_datetime__gte=datetime.now())
                                .order_by("start_datetime")
```

It has some extra features, like for example exact query searching when phrase is enclosed in quotes.